# xamarin forms, add £ to label

Tags: c#, html, xamarin.forms, label

My label:

```
 <Label Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding SubTotalForItems}"/>
```

displays the correct subtotal so for example 3.44

How can I add a £ to the beginning of this from the front end?

something like Text="£ + {Binding SubTotalForItems}"

??
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [StringFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/string-formatting)

```
 <Label Text="{Binding SubTotalForItems, StringFormat='£{0}'}" />
```